# Pass property / variable to imported beans

Tags: spring, groovy

I have a file like this:

```
beans {
  "$id"(String, "${val}")
}
```

I want to be able to pass **id** and **val**.

If I define them within the same file, it works. If I define them using bindings when loading application context, it works as well. But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
beans {

  def id = "foo"
  def val = "bar"

  importBeans("path_to_the_above_file")

}
```

The idea is to import those beans multiple times by overwriting bean id and values every time. Basically, use it as a template. Not sure it can be done. But I really hate the idea of copying all bean in the imported file just to change the IDs.

This is what I want to have an an end result:

```
beans {

  def id = "foo"
  def val = "bar"

  importBeans("path_to_the_above_file")

  id = "foo2"
  val = "bar2"

  importBeans("path_to_the_above_file")

  foo3(String, foo)
  foo4(String, foo2)
}
```

Well, I got it working by using meta class as suggested in the answer:

```
beans {

  GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.metaClass.id = "foo"
  GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.metaClass.val = "bar"

  importBeans("classpath:config/mytest.groovy")

  setId("foo2")
  setVal("bar2")

  importBeans("classpath:config/mytest.groovy")

}
```

The only downside is that I need to have ExpandoMetaClass initialized and I cannot find a way to do it from within spring groovy definition itself. I need to ether call **ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()** or have a groovy class in the project and do something like **GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.metaClass.init = {}**

Comment: What I meant by using the meta-class, was to add a method. Something like: `importBeans(String path, Map variables)`. Note: messing with the meta-class should be done outside of.. itself. Early in your app's initialization. Note: when an instance is created, it gets it's own private copy of the class' meta-class. So if you then change the class' meta-class, the instance won't see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

The `GroovyBeanDefinitionReader` doesn't provide a method to import beans while allowing you to pass in a binding. It creates it's own binding each this, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans-groovy/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/groovy/GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java#L232

What you can do instead is something like this:

```
beans {
   [
       [id: 'foo', val: 'bar'],
       [id: 'foo2', val: 'bar2']
   ].each { 
       invokeMethod(it.id, [String, it.val]) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how invokeMethod would help. It solves narrow case of String beans. But my included file is actually pretty complicated and include large number of beans. It's pretty inconvenient that you cannot pass any kind of parameters. I currently pass bean as a means of configuration but it doesn't work when I need to create multiple copies. It seems that the only way to deal with it is to copy full included file and manually changing all bean IDs. Seems like configuration nightmare but there are no other obvious options.

Comment: No need to lose hope yet! If you study the source code i linked to, i bet you can figure out enough of it to write a method that does what you need. Then you can add such a method via the meta class.

Comment: Thanks. Never done anything with meta classes but I'll try. If I find solution, I'll post the code here. I was thinking of creating a bean that would load a file with bindings and then expose it's beans. But if meta class will work better, I'll go with it.

Comment: I've deleted a few lines of your answer by accident. I don't even know how I can do it. I apologize.

Comment: No problem, I restored it. To learn about using the meta-class, research "groovy runtime metaprogramming".

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured it out. As I've said above, imported beans actually see bindings set programmatically, when loading context. I just needed to figure out how to get to that binding from groovy config script. There are 2 (or more ways). One is to create any bean or any class and set variables in its closure:

```
init(Object) {
  getBinding().setVariable("id", "food")
  getBinding().setVariable("val", "bar")
}
```

Another, and I think a better way:

```
def beanBinding = getBinding().getProperty("beans").getBinding()
beanBinding.setVariable("id", "food")
beanBinding.setVariable("val", "bar")
```